# Get list properties via JCOM

Tags: list, 2013, client-object-model

How do I get list properties like BaseTemplate, ItemCount, ListItemDeletedDate etc. via Javascript Client Object Model for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I got some answers on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/183d8571-9a2d-4efa-baca-01ac0481ba12/#183d8571-9a2d-4efa-baca-01ac0481ba12) which were very helpful.

Here is the code-snippet which helped me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    var customlist ;
    function GetListInformation(listGuid) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        customlist = oWebsite.get_lists().getById(listGuid);
        clientContext.load(customlist);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }       

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
         alert("Last item deleted time : " + this.customlist.get_lastItemDeletedDate() );
         alert("Base Type ID : " + this.customlist.get_baseType());
         alert("Item Count : " + this.customlist.get_itemCount());

    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert(" Failed");
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: here's rest of properties if you need, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547487(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @ameliapond This was 4 years ago. I don't recall how I got it to work. All I do remember is that, that snippet only pointed me in the direction I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not get your properties using REST? Unfortunately I don't have access to my SharePoint 2013 machine for testing myself, but the URL would be similar to http://'site'/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName'). You can play about directly in the browser to see the results. Once you have found the correct REST command, you could then use $.ajax() to call within your javascript.

I've written a blog about cross domain REST calls, that won't have your answer, but you will be able to see how to write a ajax call to rest.

http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/cross-domain-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-rest/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually need this for another project.